# Show an advert every five MYSQL search results

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using PHP and MYSQL to show some results from my database, this all works fine, but I want to show an advert every five search results.

At the moment the results are just pulled from the database using the

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

But i am not sure of the best way to count every five results, i did consider doing this using an id, but because the results are filtered they would not necessarily be in sequence and so i was hoping somebody could give me a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: It might be useful to explain what you're doing with those results. You would insert the advert when iterating through the results in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $i++;
   // show your mysql data here
   if($i%5==0){
      // show your ad here
   }
}
```

TIP: depending on how big your SQL result is and how exactly you are echoing it, you might probably save some mem/time by using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`, but YMMV